# TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion

Tags: python, string, object, typeerror

```
x = True
pizza = []
pizza_topping = []

while x:
    pizza_topping = input("Please enter your pizza toppings(type 'quit' to when you're done): ")
    
    if pizza_topping == 'quit':
        print(f'Thank you for your order. Your pizza toppings are: {pizza}')
        x = False
    else:
        pizza.append(pizza_topping)
        del pizza_topping[0]
```

Dear people,

I get this error:

> del pizza_topping[0] TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item
> deletion

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I changed 'break' to x = False(this was my original code). It got mixed up.

Comment: What do you expect the line `del pizza_topping[0]` to do?  It seems like if you just remove that line your code will work fine.  (You can also remove the `pizza_topping = []` at the start, it's pointless since you'll immediately reassign it; and you can also remove `x = True` and just make your loop `while True` since you never change `x`.)

Comment: Why do you need to delete it in the first place?

Comment: The error message should be pretty clear, no?

Comment: Do you want to remove the first pizza from the ```pizza``` list?

Comment: @Samwise I expected it to remove the input the user had given from the list pizza_topping. I'd like to keep the list empty.

Comment: Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have instantiated `pizza_topping` as a `list`, but you immediately start using it as a `str`. It seems like you are trying to slam too many ideas together, and not considering them. You don't need toppings and a pizza. You just need a pizza and store the toppings in it.

Most of what you are trying to do can be done on one line. You don't need to delete anything, just keep overwriting the variable. Also, your loop should be tied to the 'quit' condition. I changed that condition, because typing 'quit' to quit is cumbersome. Just type nothing and press enter to quit.

```
s_msg = 'Enter your pizza topping or press return to quit: '
e_msg = 'Thank you for your order!\nYour toppings are:\t{}' 

pizza = []

while (topping := input(s_msg)) != '':
    pizza.append(topping)
    
print(e_msg.format(', '.join(pizza)))
```

There are more things to consider, though. What if the user quits, but wants to start over? What if the topping is not a valid topping? What if your user can't spell? How does your system know that pepperoni and peperony are the same thing? These are your real challenges.

Comment: Do you mean pizza_topping converted to a string in this part of the code?: 
pizza_topping = input("Please enter your pizza toppings(type 'quit' to when you're done): ")

Comment: @sebastian1989 `input` returns a string. No matter how you type the var that receives the return from `input` it will always end up being a string once `input` returns. Essentially, you are improperly trying to delete the first letter of your topping.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answered my question! As you see I'm a real beginner haha!

Answer (score 3):

There are several things going on here:

- In Python strings are immutable, so you can't change their characters in place.

  To remove the first character of the string you can do the following:

  ```
   pizza_topping =  pizza_topping[1:]
  ```

  That being said, why do you want to remove the first character here?
- Change `pizza_topping = []` to `pizza_topping = ""`. This change doesn't affect the run of the program, but as it will hold strings there is no sense in first setting it as a list.
- Remove `x = True` and just check if `pizza_topping`  equals `'quit'` in the while's condition.
- It is preferred to give variable meaningful names (`x` is not meaningful).
- Use `','.join` to print the contents of `pizza`.

Putting it all together:

```
pizza = []

pizza_topping = ""
while pizza_topping != "quit":
    pizza_topping = input("Please enter your pizza toppings(type 'quit' to when you're done): ")
    pizza.append(pizza_topping)
print("Thank you for your order. Your pizza toppings are: " + ','.join(pizza))
```

Comment: What is the benefit of removing the first character here? He is not doing anything with it after removing it!

Comment: @ksohan I explained why he got the error and how he should go about implementing a deletion of the first character in the string. That being said, I edited my answer as it deleting the first character really doesn't make any sense here.

Answer (score 2):

as @Samwise has already said (and the variable x is also not needed) perhaps try something like (which means your code was almost correct):

```
pizza = []
while True:
    pizza_topping = input("Please enter your pizza toppings(type 'quit' to when you're done): ")
    if pizza_topping == 'quit':
        print(f'Thank you for your order. Your pizza toppings are: {pizza}')
        break
    else:
        pizza.append(pizza_topping)
```